# Server Errors after changing Template

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am new to Joomla and just took some online video training on Joomla 1.5. After installing Joomla on my website, I created a page of our portfolio, and linked it as part of the main menu.

Then, I selected a template from a portal, and installed it. However, post that, none of the links (existing as well as new) ones seems to be working. It simply reflects a server error, and gives the following message (for every page!)

---

```
The requested URL /component/content/article/34-basic/47-home was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an `ErrorDocument` to handle the request.

    Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.5 Server at nutrivalue.in Port 80
```

---

Can you help me resolve this?
Thanks!

Regards
kim

Comment: Your new templates may be looking for some files that do not exist in database. If you can upload or send a link to that template I can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Joomla 1.5? It is a very outdated and vulnerable CMS.

Anyway, try enabling SEF in your configuration settings and rename your `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` and see if that fixes the problem.